# Fails to build pinkimage library with python support under ubuntu 13.04 (32)

Tags: python, ubuntu, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

[pinkimage](https://pinkhq.com/homepage/index.html) is a library for image processing with several modules related to mathematical morphology. I am trying to build it under ubuntu 13.04 (32 bits).

- I have downloaded the source from svn
- I try to produce the make files with cmake-gui. If the option PYTHON_FRONT_END is checked, the process fails with the message:

```
Boost version: 1.49.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  python
  thread
  system
  date_time
Looking for C++ include boost/shared_ptr.hpp
Looking for C++ include boost/shared_ptr.hpp - found
Looking for C++ include boost/shared_array.hpp
Looking for C++ include boost/shared_array.hpp - found
Looking for C++ include boost/python/list.hpp
Looking for C++ include boost/python/list.hpp - not found
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:437 (message):
  error boost/python/list.hpp does not compile.  You need at least version
  1.37 or newer.  Check if its correctly installed.  There is a known issue.
  If PYTHON_LIBRARY='/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so' does not point
  to the correct location of python's libraries, please specify them manually
  or delete the file in question.  (seen on OpenSuSE 11.2)
```

Every boost related libraries are installed. When the option PYTHON_FRONT_END is not checked, the configurartion step succeeds in generating make files.
I don't know how  to follow the message indication :" ... please specify them manually...".
I suppose that I have to do something like:

```
export PYTHON_LIBRARY=/some/path
```

I tried for example:

```
$ export PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/share/lintian/overrides
```

because the command ***locate boost*** finds some stuff related to python and boost, but that doesn't fix the cmake problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/pink-image-devel/2012-July/000155.html) is a run through of the build, with its set of usual errors. I have not built it recently - but will get back once i have a linux machine!